# PHP set random variable from proxy list and Curl, if fail repeat

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to figure out how to randomly select a proxy ip from a list and then performing a curl with it, and if a fail occurs use a new proxy ip. Here is my working code without the randomization:

```
    $url       = "www.example.com";
    $loginpassw = 'myproxypw';

    $proxy_ip = '23.27.37.128';
    $proxy_port = '29842';

    $ch        = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $loginpassw);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600);
    $html  = curl_exec($ch);    

    if (strpos($html,'To continue, please type the characters below') !== false) {
        echo "now an error has occurred, let's try a new proxy";
    }

    curl_close($ch);
```

Ideally the `proxy_ip` and `proxy_port` must stay the same in a list of say:

```
$proxylist = array (
            array("ip" => "23.27.37.128", "port" => "29842"),
            array("ip" => "23.27.37.111", "port" => "29852"),
            array("ip" => "23.27.37.112", "port" => "29742"),
            array("ip" => "23.27.37.151", "port" => "29242")
             );
```

I was wondering if I could possibly use shuffle:

```
shuffle($proxylist);

while($element = array_pop($proxylist)){
  return $element;
}
```

My second question would be the best way of doing this, my PHP is not perfect so I am wondering rather than rewriting the top curl over and over should I store it inside a function?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Simon

## Edit:

The following code seems to be working where I have split my code into two functions:

```
    function curltime($url, $proxy_ip, $proxy_port, $loginpassw){
            $ch        = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $loginpassw);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600);
            return curl_exec($ch);  
            curl_close($ch);
    }

//now let's do the curl

            $url       = "www.example.com";
            $proxylist = array (
            array("proxyip" => "23.27.37.128", "proxyport" => "29842"),
            array("proxyip" => "23.27.37.111", "proxyport" => "29852"),
            array("proxyip" => "23.27.37.112", "proxyport" => "29742"),
            array("proxyip" => "23.27.37.151", "proxyport" => "29242")
             );
            foreach ($proxylist[mt_rand(0,count($proxylist)-1)] as $key => $value) {
                $$key = $value;
            }
            $html = $this->curltime($url, $proxyip, $proxyport, 'somepassword');


            if (strpos($html,'To continue, please type the characters below') !== false) {
                echo "now we have errors so let's try again" 
            foreach ($proxylist[mt_rand(0,count($proxylist)-1)] as $key => $value) {
                $$key = $value;
            }
            $html = $this->curltime($url, $proxyip, $proxyport, 'somepassword');
            }
            $cache .= $html;
```

## Anyone know of a better way for me to do the looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a random proxy from the list you could use this:

```
$proxylist[mt_rand(0,count($proxylist)-1)]
```

Explained:

`count($array)` Get length of array

`mt_rand($x,$y)` Get a random number between `$x` and `$y`

Edit:

It is totaly possible to do like you did also. Then just always take like the first element of the array.

```
shuffle($array);
$array[0]
```

Which of these two options are best for the randomness I can't really say though.

Comment: Thankyou, I'm just testing this now

Comment: Awesome, this is doing the trick I am going to edit my post. I am wondering if their is a better way of doing this, for example rather than doing random in which case it might just use the same blocked proxy do the next one down.

Comment: Am going to accept this as the answer for now, but will keep looking for a better way of doing this. Thanks for the help.